# What are resources for building a static analyzer for C in C?

Tags: c, parsing, static-analysis

I have a school project to develop a static analyzer in C for C.

Where should I start? What are some resources which could assist me?

I am assuming I will need to parse C, so what are some good parsers for C or tools for building C parsers?

Comment: What's a statistic analyzer for C? What does it analyze?

Comment: What level of static analysis are you being asked to tackle? Are we talking building a lint? Or something more robust. Filling out the details to a degree would help us.

Comment: @Jordan - I was asked for making the general one, as an analyzer of buffer overflow, arithmetic overflow..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first take yourself over to [antlr](http://www.antlr.org/), look at its [getting started guide](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/FAQ+-+Getting+Started), it has a wealth of information about parsing etc.., I personally use antlr as it gives a choice of [code generation targets](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Code+Generation+Targets).

To use antlr you need a [c or c++ grammar file](http://www.antlr.org/grammar/list), pick of these up and start playing.

Anyway have fun with it..

Answer (score 1):

Probably your best starting point would by [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) (with the proviso that it already has a static analyzer, so unless you want to write one for its own sake, you might be better off using/enhancing the existing one).

Comment: It _is_ a school project, OP might need to start from scratch.

Comment: @Chris Lutz: It could well be. Without knowing the assignment, it's hard to guess exactly what he needs to do...

Comment: Clang is written in C++ so might not be allowed for this project.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you want to write the analyzer in C?

If you were using a modern langauge (e.g. C#, Java, Python), then I would second spgennard's suggestion of ANTLR for the parser.

If writing the analyzer in C is a requirement then you are stuck with lex and yacc (flex and bison) or maybe a hand-crafted parser.

Looks like [Uno](http://spinroot.com/uno/) comes close to what you want to do.  It uses lex/yacc and includes the grammar files.  The analysis part however is written in C++.

Maybe you can get some more ideas about the how and what from tools listed at [SpinRoot](http://spinroot.com/static/).  Wikipedia also has some good info.

Comment: You don't want to write your own parser for C (and you really don't want to do this for C++), unless you want to spend all your time getting the parser right and none of it working on the static analyzer. Get a front end that already does the parsing *and* the name and type resolution for you.

Answer (score 1):

Parsing is the easiest and least important part of a static analyser. Antlr was already suggested, it should be sufficient for parsing plain C (but not C++). Just a little tip - do not implement your own preprocessor, better reuse the output of `gcc -E`.

As for the rest, you can take a look at some of the existing analysers sources, namely Clang and [CIL](http://cil.sourceforge.net/), read about an [SSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form) representation and [abstract interpretation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_interpretation). Choosing the right intermediate representation for your code is a key.

I doubt it can be an easy task in plain C, so you'd probably end up implementing some sort of DSL on top of it to handle ASTs and transforms. Sounds like something much bigger than a typical school project.